# Libertine Mono and lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, libertine

Using lualatex on latest TeXLive 2012 I am not able to select Libertine Mono by its full name via fontspec. luaotfload is finding the font and it is written into `~/.texlive2012/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua`

However I am able to select the different styles by their psname like `LinLibertineMO`. Is there something wrong with the font itself or am I doing something wrong?

**edit:** As requestet a working example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
% \setmonofont{Linux Libertine Mono O}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Uncommenting `setmonofont` leads to not working:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "LinuxLibertineMonoO" cannot be found.
!  
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
```

Here’s an excerpt from `~/.texlive2012/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua`

```
{
["familyname"]="Linux Libertine Mono O",
["filename"]={ "LinLibertine_M.otf", false },
["fontname"]="LinLibertineMO",
["fullname"]="Linux Libertine Mono O",
["names"]={
 ["family"]="Linux Libertine Mono O",
 ["fullname"]="Linux Libertine Mono O",
 ["psname"]="LinLibertineMO",
 ["subfamily"]="Mono",
},
```

Comment: Can you apply this patch: https://gist.github.com/phi-gamma/5457042 to ``otfl-font-nms.lua`` and test again?
It would appear that Libertine Mono has a quirk wrt to subfamily designation.

Comment: I applied the patch and now lualatex compiles, but the mono font is now apparently the bold oblique variant. I guess there’s something wrong with the font itself.

Comment: Ok, I have [updated the gist](https://gist.github.com/phi-gamma/5457042) with a test for the font name; it should now match the non-bold variants unless requested otherwise.
Thanks for testing.
Fwiw, with problems like this, run ``otfinfo -i`` on the font file to list possible identifiers.
The safe bet is almost always on what the field *Postscript name* says (“LinLibertineMO” in this case).

Comment: Yep, now it works. Could you submit your patch upstream? 

The problem with the postcript name is, that one can only select a specific style (regular, italic, bold, etc.).

Comment: It’s [on its way](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/pull/8). Hopefully it will make it into the next bugfix release. You’re right, of course, that the automation fontspec does is probably not possible when working with psname/filename based loading.

Comment: This question was related to a bug in Libertine Mono, which has been corrected.